# "Unable to rollback transaction" error in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I am trying to run the following query to create my nodes and relationships from a .csv file that I have:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///LoanStats3bEDITED.csv' AS line 
//USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 makes sure we don't get a memory error
//creating the nodes with their properties
//member node
CREATE (member:Person{member_id:TOINT(line.member_id)})
//Personal information node
CREATE (personalInformation:PersonalInformation{addr_state:line.addr_state})
//recordHistory node
CREATE (recordHistory:RecordHistory{delinq_2yrs:TOFLOAT(line.delinq_2yrs),earliest_cr_line:line.earliest_cr_line,inq_last_6mths:TOFLOAT(line.inq_last_6mths),collections_12_mths_ex_med:TOFLOAT(line.collections_12_mths_ex_med),delinq_amnt:TOFLOAT(line.delinq_amnt),percent_bc_gt_75:TOFLOAT(line.percent_bc_gt_75), pub_rec_bankruptcies:TOFLOAT(line.pub_rec_bankruptcies), tax_liens:TOFLOAT(line.tax_liens)})
//Loan node
CREATE (loan:Loan{funded_amnt:TOFLOAT(line.funded_amnt),term:line.term, int_rate:line.int_rate, installment:TOFLOAT(line.installment),purpose:line.purpose})
//Customer Finances node
CREATE (customerFinances:CustomerFinances{emp_length:line.emp_length,verification_status_joint:line.verification_status_joint,home_ownership:line.home_ownership, annual_inc:TOFLOAT(line.annual_inc), verification_status:line.verification_status,dti:TOFLOAT(line.dti), annual_inc_joint:TOFLOAT(line.annual_inc_joint),dti_joint:TOFLOAT(line.dti_joint)})
//Accounts node
CREATE (accounts:Accounts{revol_util:line.revol_util,tot_cur_bal:TOFLOAT(line.tot_cur_bal)})

//creating the relationships
CREATE UNIQUE (member)-[:FINANCIAL{issue_d:line.issue_d,loan_status:line.loan_status, application_type:line.application_type}]->(loan)
CREATE UNIQUE (customerFinances)<-[:FINANCIAL]-(member)
CREATE UNIQUE (accounts)<-[:FINANCIAL{open_acc:TOINT(line.open_acc),total_acc:TOFLOAT(line.total_acc)}]-(member)
CREATE UNIQUE (personalInformation)<-[:PERSONAL]-(member)
CREATE UNIQUE (recordHistory)<-[:HISTORY]-(member)
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
Unable to rollback transaction
```

What does this mean and how can I fix my query so it can be run successfully?

I am now getting the following error:

```
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are out of memory. 
Solutions:

Use neo4j-import.batch

Split your querys.

Make constraints to speed up the querys.

Why do you need the create unique? You could just use create if your csv is clean, or use merge.

I think it could also be faster if you execute the query not in the browser but in shell.

Download more ram :-)

Comment: Getting rid of the "unique" in the creation of the relationships helped!

Answer (score 0):

If you really need the uniqueness of relationships, replace `create unique` with `merge`.

Also, your repeated `MERGE` operation on `FINANCIAL` causes Cypher to materialize the whole result before each of the 3 operations with an `Eager` operator so that it doesn't run into endless loops.

That's why the periodic commit is not going into effect, causing the whole intermediate result to use too much memory.

Something else you could do is to use the APOC library and `apoc.periodic.iterate` instead for batching.

```
call apoc.periodic.iterate("
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///LoanStats3bEDITED.csv' AS line RETURN line
","
//member node
CREATE (member:Person{member_id:TOINT(line.member_id)})
//Personal information node
CREATE (personalInformation:PersonalInformation{addr_state:line.addr_state})
//recordHistory node
CREATE (recordHistory:RecordHistory{delinq_2yrs:TOFLOAT(line.delinq_2yrs),earliest_cr_line:line.earliest_cr_line,inq_last_6mths:TOFLOAT(line.inq_last_6mths),collections_12_mths_ex_med:TOFLOAT(line.collections_12_mths_ex_med),delinq_amnt:TOFLOAT(line.delinq_amnt),percent_bc_gt_75:TOFLOAT(line.percent_bc_gt_75), pub_rec_bankruptcies:TOFLOAT(line.pub_rec_bankruptcies), tax_liens:TOFLOAT(line.tax_liens)})
//Loan node
CREATE (loan:Loan{funded_amnt:TOFLOAT(line.funded_amnt),term:line.term, int_rate:line.int_rate, installment:TOFLOAT(line.installment),purpose:line.purpose})
//Customer Finances node
CREATE (customerFinances:CustomerFinances{emp_length:line.emp_length,verification_status_joint:line.verification_status_joint,home_ownership:line.home_ownership, annual_inc:TOFLOAT(line.annual_inc), verification_status:line.verification_status,dti:TOFLOAT(line.dti), annual_inc_joint:TOFLOAT(line.annual_inc_joint),dti_joint:TOFLOAT(line.dti_joint)})
//Accounts node
CREATE (accounts:Accounts{revol_util:line.revol_util,tot_cur_bal:TOFLOAT(line.tot_cur_bal)})

//creating the relationships
MERGE (member)-[:FINANCIAL{issue_d:line.issue_d,loan_status:line.loan_status, application_type:line.application_type}]->(loan)
MERGE (customerFinances)<-[:FINANCIAL]-(member)
MERGE (accounts)<-[:FINANCIAL{open_acc:TOINT(line.open_acc),total_acc:TOFLOAT(line.total_acc)}]-(member)
MERGE (personalInformation)<-[:PERSONAL]-(member)
MERGE (recordHistory)<-[:HISTORY]-(member)
", {batchSize:1000, iterateList:true})
```